# How do I make these css background transitions smoother?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

I have a background slideshow on my site that changes picture every 5 seconds.

Here is the Javascript/Jquery:

```
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = '../img/hero1.jpg';
backgrounds[1] = '../img/hero2.jpg';
backgrounds[2] = '../img/hero3.jpg';

function changeBackground() {
currentBackground++;
if(currentBackground > 2) currentBackground = 0;

$('.heroImg').fadeOut(300,function() {
    $('.heroImg').css({
        'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
    });
    $('.heroImg').fadeIn(300);
});

setTimeout(changeBackground, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(changeBackground, 5000);        
});
```

At the moment, the images fade to white, then to the next image.

How can I alter this code so that the images fade over each other instead?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should only fadeIn images and not fadeOut them , maybe it will be make a better effect ?